# Opening a link within the same page using javascript or ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, hyperlink

What I have is a list of links in my left sidebar and a main content area to the right,
I want to be able to click the links to the left and have each "page" open in the content area, instead of reloading a new page. I'm sure this is fairly easy using javascript or ajax, I'm just not sure how.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your question is a little too broad. For example. What do you want to load from your server when clicking on links. Pieces of html that are ready to be appeded? Data  models? Whole page markup? If you are using jQuery, I would suggest to take a look at $().on and $.ajax methods. For vanilla js the same is accomplished with addEventListener and XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I want to load another html page within the content area, I thought I specified that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have

```
<div id='content'></div>
```

on the right side and a link on the left

```
<a href='#' id='contact_link'>Contact</a>
```

You can use JQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load the div with the content of a page when you click the link:

```
$("#contact_link").click(function() {
    $("#content").load("contact.html");
});
```

If you're not using JQuery you can get it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp), otherwise there are ways to do it in plain JS.

Comment: It's a rather large assumption to make that the OP is using jQuery. Nowhere in the post does the OP specify this...

Comment: The jQuery works, well attempts to work, because when I click the link, it pops up in the content and says "error loading page", not sure where to go from there...

Comment: @shibby1024 If you're in Chrome, right click -> Inspect Element -> Console. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @War10ck the OP also didn't provide too many clues. From there jQuery is the first assumption.

Comment: Honestly I was looking for any solution... doesn't matter if it was jQuery or not.